# Facing an 'Error: socket hang up' when using vi.advanceTimersByTime in Unit Testing Vue component

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, vite, vitest

While trying to test a Vue component having some async call to backend service. Due to this, the html of the mounted component is not rendered before expect statements in Unit test.
So, we have added `vi.useFakeTimers()` and `await vi.advanceTimersByTime` which is allowing the async calls to complete before rendering the html. This has solved the above issue but due to `await vi.advanceTimersByTime`, we are getting Error: socket hang up in console while running our test cases.

Have tried replacing `await vi.advanceTimersByTime(<mills>)` with `await setTimeout(() => {},<mills>)` but this setTimeout is not working when we are trying to trigger any DOM events like setValue or trigger('click')

```
Stack trace:
    Error: Error: socket hang up
        at Object.dispatchError 
    (<project>\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\xhr-utils.js:63:19)
        at Request.<anonymous> 
    (<project>\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:655:18)
        at Request.emit (node:events:532:35)
        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> 
    (<project>\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\http-request.js:121:14)
        at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:520:28)
        at Socket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:415:11)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:532:35)
        at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
```

*Note: replaced the file path with  in the stack trace*

Due to await vi.advanceTimersByTime, we are getting Error: socket hang up in console while running our test cases.

```
    const wrapper = wrapperFactory();
    await nextTick();
    await vi.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
    await wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate();
    const zipInput = wrapper.find("input[type=text]");
    const submitBtn = wrapper.find("button");
    await zipInput.setValue("12345");
    await submitBtn.trigger("click");
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
```

Note that the test case itself is passing.
Expecting test case to not have any console errors.